# How can I avoid the Adversary's homing Brimstone?

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac-rebirth

Of the many times I've been shot by the Adversary's homing Brimstone, I've managed to avoid it just a couple of times. So, I know it's avoidable, but I don't know how to do it reliably.

Usually when I get there it becomes a power check: if I can dispatch him before letting him shoot his first Brimstone I have good chances to end the run victorious. The problem is I'd like to have a chance to end even those runs when I have less firepower, but usually in those cases if I get the Adversary my run stops there.

Comment: I can't upvote this hard enough. A way to consistently evade his stupid brimstone would be awesome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Adversary picks a direction to shoot, then charges up, then shoots. And the homing only goes so far. When you expect him to fire that brimstone, just do a quarter turn around him. Or you can constantly move, circle around him without stopping, and the shots won't get you.

[A video that kinda shows this](http://youtu.be/YE6PbnFCUCI?t=15m22s)

Comment: But what to do on double Adversary rooms where circlestrafing isn't applicable anymore!

Comment: @No.7892142 Kill one before it shoots :|

Comment: If I can do that, then I don't even need tactics to deal with the shot anyway, as I'd be hella overpowered at that point.

Comment: @No.7892142 That's kinda the point of the very last floor, which is I think the only floor where double Adversary can appear.

Comment: And that's exactly my problem with the Isaac lategame. The game gets real unfair at that point, i.e. unavoidable damage en masse. But yeah, single Adversary can just be circlestrafed to death anyway. (Oop, accdently posted that as an answer.)

Comment: @BlaXpirit that's not true, you can get a "Double trouble" boss room in Depths with 2 Adversary, trust me...